# What does the 'position' mean and how to find the position

Tags: javascript, json, eslint

Today when I run `npx eslint --fix ./` in powershell it logs `Unexpected token } in JSON at position 93` in .eslintrc.json.So I totally have to questions here:
1. What does 'position 93' mean and how to find the exact position in my code,cause I have no idea of 93, I used to find the position when the console logs that the Error located at which line(column).
2. It seems like that my .eslintrc.json have no syntax error,Could you guys help me find the problem?

```
{
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true,
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            4
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "windows"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the trailing comma after `"es6": true,`

Comment: Json files should not have trailing commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `comma` in line `"es6": true,`

You should paste your json into tool check validate json format.

Ex: https://jsoneditoronline.org/ is tool json format online

Comment: Thank u very much for solving my problem!But could you give me a little suggestion on how to find the position such as `position 93`?

Comment: because your json format is not validate, so console logs maybe show the error incorrect

Answer (score 0):

If a single number is given. That means it's the character index in the file. For example:

```
//Hello
"The following dot is in position 52"
console.log('test');
       ^
       |___ this is position 52 (or 54 if your file contains "\r\n" as newlines)
```

And yes, you need to count line endings as either one or two bytes depending on weather it has Windows line endings (CRLF) or Unix line endings (LF).

Though, interestingly, multi-byte unicode characters are counted as one character instead of multiple bytes (this is because unlike multi-byte characters, both "\r" and "\n" are separate characters).

If two numbers are given, sometimes with a `:` in between, then the first number is the line number and the second the column number (character index from start of line). So the dot above would sometimes be referred to as `position 3:7` or `line 3 position 7` or `line 3 column 7`.

Comment: Ah ha!Thank u very for the detailed answer.Now I no how to find the exact position when there is only a single number:D